# Why does querying an assembly's types via reflection cause the program to unexpectedly hang while debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

Using this code stops responding my program.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\test\test.exe");
Type[] typesInAssembly = assembly.GetTypes();
```

in debugging mode this code stops responding when the second line executing.

I changed `test.exe` to something empty WindowsformApplication.exe, and it works.
I don't know why it is not working with `test.exe`.
I put breakpoint  and checked Locals in debugging Locals section and i saw some error icons there i pasted them below. I hope someone help me about this.

```
    DefinedTypes    Function evaluation timed out.  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Reflection.TypeInfo>
    EntryPoint  Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Reflection.MethodInfo
    EscapedCodeBase Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. string
    Evidence    Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Security.Policy.Evidence
    ExportedTypes   Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Type>
    FullName    Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. string
    GlobalAssemblyCache Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. bool
    HostContext Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. long
    ImageRuntimeVersion Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. string
    IsDynamic   Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. bool
    IsFullyTrusted  Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. bool
    Location    Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. string
    ManifestModule  Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Reflection.Module
    Modules Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Reflection.Module>
    PermissionSet   Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Security.PermissionSet
    ReflectionOnly  Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. bool
    SecurityRuleSet Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Security.SecurityRuleSet
```

Answer (score 0):

This plagued me once before as well. The issue I had, which may be the same as yours, is that I had the executable I was inspecting running under a debugger in another environment. This caused the file to be locked. I could load the file into a reflection only context but when I tried to query the types, it would hang.

So, make sure:

- You have no process open with the executable you are loading
- You do not have the executable loaded elsewhere, perhaps paused by a debugger
- Your program using reflection has sufficient privileges to access the file

After you verify those things, try restarting your computer and trying again. If it works, it was a resource acquisition problem. If it does not, please upload your executable, if you can, and I can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: in Debuging options, general section unchecking Enable property Evaluation and other implicit function Calls solved this messages but after compiled code i put  Break point for assembly and  checked in locals and implicit function evaluation turned off by user.        I can evaluate in there. for example EntryPoint . But i couldnt evaluate  DefinedTypes in that section. It says same message when i try to evaluate